# What might happen if someone poured 10^40 liters of water onto the sun?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, physics, space, astronomy

For reference, a 10^40 liter sphere has a radius of 10 au.

Comment: This might be better served in the Physics SE or Astronomy SE. Also, 10 AU is an absurdly huge number for a radius. For scale, the radius of the sun itself is roughly 1/215th of an AU. So it's not really "pouring it onto the sun" and more of "the sun being engulfed by an impossibly big sphere of water"

Comment: Depends on what poring means. Most likely. Boom... supernova. That ball is orders of magnatude heavier than the sun.

Comment: Ask xkcd.  I'm sure Randall Munroe has done a What If on something similar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a physics question answered by https://what-if.xkcd.com/14/

Comment: For one thing, the surface of the sun is something like 6000 kelvin. I think the pressure at the bottom of 10 au of water might be something like 10^11 atmospheres. What phase would water be in under those conditions?

Comment: This isn't a worldbuilding question per our [tour] and [help] pages.  If you can provide information that justifies the question as being worldbuilding (like how the water got there and why anyone would do this in the first place), then I'll retract my vote.

Comment: even if you can pour the water the gravitational force experienced by these water molecular will cause them to heat up probably reaching millions of degree Celsius, since water is made of hydrogen and oxygen which can be fused to produce more energy but I'm unsure if the pressure from the nuclear fusion can overcome its weight... im just saying ;D

Answer (score 4):

A sphere of $10^{40}$ L of water at standard density has a mass of $10^{40}$ kg.  The sun has a mass of only $2\times 10^{30}$ kg and the entire Milky Way galaxy has a mass of about $10^{12}$ solar masses.

So that water sphere represents about half a percent of the mass of the entire galaxy.

> For reference, a 10^40 liter sphere has a radius of 10 au.

No it does not.

It would in fact collapse into a Black Hole.  This is absolutely impossible to avoid, but it would also most likely produce a huge super nova as well in the process of collapse.

And long before you gathered even a small fraction of that $10^{40}$ L it would have enough mass to collapse into a star (with an Oxygen-Hydrogen fusion core) and as you added a bit more water it would eventually be large enough to collapse into a black hole.  And at that point you'd still have almost all of the $10^{40}$ L left, because the amount of water required to form a black hole is only $4\times 10^{30}$ kg, twice the Sun's mass and one billionth of your total water supply.

Now in practice you'd need way more water to make a star with an active core collapse into a Black hole ( as opposed to just becoming a bigger star ).  However there is a limit and [it's something like 150 solar masses](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/328/is-there-a-theoretical-maximum-size-limit-for-a-star#333) ( still way smaller than your sphere ).

But one way or another you get a black hole.

A black hole of mass $10^{40}$ kg has a radius of about $93$ AU.  And yes, that *is* larger than a sphere of water of standard density of the same mass.

Comment: I'm curious as to just what would happen if you dumped a reasonably large amount of water on a star.  Though of course the 10 AU sphere is not possible, say it's a mass comparable to what a close binary might steal from its neighbor.  There's a fast oxygen-fusion reaction in old stars, but that happens when the hydrogen in the core is exhausted.  Would H2O do something different?

Comment: @jamesqf under those temperatures and pressures, H2O would undergo fusion just as any other element or compound. The sun is not a wooden ball on fire.

Comment: I was going to say the same. Any question that starts with an astronomically-large (pun intended) amount of stuff always has the same answer - a black hole.

Comment: @B.fox: To start with, H2O wouldn't exist on a star like the sun, because it would disassociate into (highly ionized) H and O atoms.  Then H and O undergo different fusion processes.  Then too, fusion occurs only towards the core of the star, not at the surface.  So you have a large mass of infalling H20, disassociating as it heats to extreme temperatures due to gravitational potential energy...  Do you get fusion ignition just from that?